# colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can I use in matplotlib colors expect from red-->r green-->g is there any list how we have to type the color?

example:

```
plt.axvspan(73, 104, facecolor='r', alpha=0.2)
```

it takes the red, another assect for facecolor?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any RGB value as a tuple of three float numbers. Alternatively, you can also use the HTML style, e.g. red could be written as '#FF0000'. For details see the [matplotlib color documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html)

An example could read

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axvspan(76, 77, edgecolor='#cc33ff', facecolor=(1.0, 0.5, 0.5), alpha=1)
plt.xlim(50, 80)
plt.show()
```

Note the different version of specifying and edge color and a face color.

Comment: can you provide me an example in the above axvspan?

Comment: I included an example. By the way, you should probably also take a look at `plt.axvline` if you only want to draw a line as indicated by your span of zero width.